# how does data-render attribute works in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain the functionality of `data-render="true"` attribute works in javascript and how to use it in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what that would be is a **data attribute**. I am not sure if this is the main use, but I know it makes sending data from html to javascript very easy. [Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

I used it in a project when ids for a table were created at runtime, and depending on the row clicked on, grabbed the data attribute.

To go to your question, I believe that is what is happening with the data-render. It is just a "variable" to store a boolean in a sense.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 specification, you are allowed to create attributes into your tags.

The specification recommends that you use some naming guidelines to create your own tags, thus as using something like "data-[some namespace to define your project]-[attribute_name]"

You can access those attributes in js, and load them with data when your server returns the page to the client. These type of attributes allow you to communicate data between server and client codes in a quite simple and clean way.